# Pagination using ListView and a dynamic/filtered queryset

Tags: django, pagination, django-queryset, django-class-based-views, django-pagination

I have a class based view that I am using to display a queryset in a table. I am also using a couple formsets to filter this queryset. I am using the `get_queryset()` method provided as part of the `generic.ListView` class to filter the diplayed results. Here is basically what my class looks like:

```
from django.views import generic

class UnifiedSingleSearch(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'app/foo.html'
    model = MyModel
    paginate_by = 30

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.POST:  # If we got here because of a search submission, filter
            return MyModel.objects.filter('Some stuff base on the POST data')
        return MyModel.objects.all()  # Otherwise, just show everything
```

Because I am using a formset to submit multiple search criteria, I have to use a POST request. Upon initial submission of the form, the page reloads with a correctly filtered querset. However when I try to use my pagination controls, the POST request is thrown away and the page acts as if I am going to page#2 of `MyModel.objects.all()` instead of my filtered down subset.

**How can I retain my filtered queryset when using pagination controls?**

Here is the HTML for the pagination controls:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
        <nav aria-label="Pagination nav">
            <ul class="pagination">
                {# Back a page #}
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&#10094;</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <span class="page-link">&#10094;</span>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                {# Page numbers #}
                {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                        <li class="page-item active">
                            <span class="page-link">{{ i }}
                                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {# Next page #}
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&#10095;</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <span class="page-link">&#10095;</span>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <p>No MyModel objects found</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Frequently searches are done through `GET` because of two reasons: (a) the parameters can easily get passed through the next page, and (b) because the query is encoded, you can share the URL to another user that then also obtains the search results.

Comment: There's a semantic reason too; GET means "fetch me the information from the server according to these parameters" whereas POST means "make a change on the server using these values", which you're not doing.

Comment: That makes sense. I did some testing and I will try to switch over to GET. If it works ill close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to a GET request was the answer. Pagination controls also had to be edited a bit to retain the passed querystring. They should all include `{{ request.GET.urlencode }}` and then you tack on the page logic to the end like usual. Ends up looking something like this:

```
<li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&#10095;</a>
</li>
```